# Azure DNS Records does not propagate

Tags: azure, dns, office365, azure-dns

I have added 3 DNS records (MX, CNAME, TXT) to set up office 365 but only one record(MX) propagated.
The following two records do not propagated yet. I have added records on Wed Dec 04, 2019 19:13:27 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) and now it has been 23 HRS. Is there any way to forcefully propagate these records?

**CNAME**

Host: autodiscover

Value:autodiscover.outlook.com

**TXT**

Host:@

Value:v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com -all

[image]

Comment: Besides the fact that your question is offtopic, DNS has no propagation, contrary to popular belief. If you gave the names people could have helped but here noone does. You need to query the authoritative nameservers for your domain to see if the changes are publish.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I already logged multiple tickets with Azure to analyze this matter.  For e.g here is the post I have added in MSDN. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2e237779-3441-4853-962f-046c5fcc332f/dns-records-does-not-propagate?forum=WAVirtualMachinesVirtualNetwork                                                 Posted here to see if anyone faced a similar situation.

Comment: Can you share the real domain name?

Comment: "Posted here to see if anyone faced a similar situation"  But "here" is a website related to programming question, not a generic forum for questions on any issue. Management of DNS configuration is not really a programming topic. Also, in general, crossposting a given question on multiple sites is not always a good idea: you may have multiple duplicate discussions then, and if a solution is found in one case, it won't be seen in the other. You should find the best canonical place to post your question and post only there.

Comment: If this issue is fixed, could you share your solution? this will benefit other members.

Comment: @NancyXiong Firstly, Thank you very much for your detailed answer. Unfortunately, the issue is still exist and Azure support team is investigating it. Once the issue is fixed, I will update the question.

Comment: @Sampath Could you share your solution please.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you host your DNS records in the Azure DNS zones. You first need to change your domain's name servers at your domain registrar's website yourself, follow [these steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/dns/create-dns-records-for-azure-dns-zones?view=o365-worldwide#change-your-domains-nameserver-ns-records). As far as I know, it depends on your domain register, this entire process can take from a few hours to up to 72 hours for the DNS update across the Internet's DNS system.

Secondly, ensure that you have [created DNS records for Azure DNS zones to work with Office 365 services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/dns/create-dns-records-for-azure-dns-zones?view=o365-worldwide#change-your-domains-nameserver-ns-records) correctly, especially, the [TXT record](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/dns/create-dns-records-for-azure-dns-zones?view=o365-worldwide#add-a-txt-record-for-spf-to-help-prevent-email-spam). When you copy and paste the value of the DNS records, make sure there is not any space or typo.

The following tools help you confirm in which locations your DNS has updated:

- [What's my DNS?](https://www.whatsmydns.net/)
- [DNS Propagation Checker](https://viewdns.info/propagation/)
- [DNS Unlimited](https://www.dnsunlimited.com/propagation_check)

For more troubleshooting information, you could refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/get-help-with-domains/find-and-fix-issues?view=o365-worldwide). If there is a long time for DNS records propagation, I suggest directly contacting the Azure DNS or [Office 365 support](https://support.office.com/).